# Grouping Excel rows based on similar values using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have `report.xlsx` file which contains data from 2 other excel workbook which got merged based on some unique value. `Pool_RAM` column has data from `file1.xlsx` and `Pool_HDD` column has data from `file2.xlsx`. Both the column contains some duplicate values. Now I want to group the rows based on similar values and put in format as mentioned below.

`Report.xlsx Actual Data`

[image]

And I want data to in the below format.

`Expected Format`

[image]

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: +1 @SiddharthRout -> I would even add, what is your real question? it's not very clear.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman: I presume the question is in the title. I believe the user wants to group values in a row after the merge happens based on similar values like `113e1fb6-8998-ad9c-fbd0-61101ef544ac` and `113e1fb6-8998-ad9c-fbd0-61101ef544ac`

Comment: @SiddharthRout  :- Actually question got posted in middle of writing . Please see the screenshot which i attached. Yeah i want group the rows in based on similar values.

Comment: @Scott Holtzman :- Actually question got posted in middle of writing

Comment: @user1023123: Please refer to my 1st comment.

Comment: @SiddharthRout:- I am very new to this Excel Marco,i have no experience in writing Marco, but yes i know the way how to do it but can't put in respective syntax. Steps 1:- Take the value from column 1 and compare the value in column2 till you get the same value. Step 2:- Compare the Next Value of Column 1 to previous compared value of column 1 ,if is same ,proceed to next value in column 1. --- You must have good approach than me.

Comment: @shaktiK: `I am very new to this Excel Marco` Umm, in that case this exercise may turn out slightly complex for you. If you are willing to learn then I can help you with this.

Comment: @SiddharthRout :- Thanks! would like to learn .Please help!!

Comment: Here is the logic.
1. Define an object for the sheet which has the data
2. Add a temp sheet for output
3. Get last Row of Col G of the sheet which has the data
4. Sort the data in Col G in ascending order
5. Get last Row of Col F of the sheet which has the data
6. Sort the data in Col F in ascending order
7. Add values from Col F in a unique collection
8. Set the row for output in the new sheet
9. Loop through the unique collection

Comment: 10. Get the occurances in Col F and Col G for each item in the collection and store them in a variable say FCount and GCount
11. Ascertain which is greater; FCount or GCount? Or are they equal
12. Write to Col A and Col B of output sheet
13. Skipping a row for a blank row
14. Set the next row for output

Comment: Ok which one of these steps you don't know?

Comment: I have upvoted your question and hope few other members also do so that we can automatically move this discussion to chat.

Comment: @SiddharthRout :- Thanks for your prompt reply, All the columns are in sorted state.
let me try once the steps you provided, will update you on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this macro and adjust it to your needs:

```
Sub GroupMyData()
'Assuming the data source is in column F and G, from row 2 to 1000
'The result will be put in column K and L
'part1: filter to unique values, put in column J temporarily
    Range("F2:F1000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("J2" _
        ), Unique:=True

'part2: fill the data
    Range("K1") = Range("F1")
    Range("L1") = Range("G1")
    Range("J2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    n = Selection.Count
    Range("K2").Select
    ck = 2
    cl = 2
    For i = 1 To n
      txt = Range("J" & (i + 1))
      numf = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("F2:F1000"), txt)
      For j = 1 To numf
        Range("K" & ck) = txt
        ck = ck + 1
      Next
      numg = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("G2:G1000"), txt)
      For j = 1 To numg
        Range("L" & cl) = txt
        cl = cl + 1
      Next
      If (ck > cl) Then
        cl = ck
      Else
        ck = cl
      End If
      ck = ck + 1
      cl = cl + 1
    Next
'part 3: delete the temporary data
    Range("J2:J1000").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("K2").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: "Range("F2:F1000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("J2" _
        ), Unique:=True "    while running this macro its throwing some error, Object required. also i am not getting hint how to solve this. Please help

Comment: @ShaktiK: It works for me on Excel 2007. See the sample file at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/67854233/Book2.xls